# Icon for "upgrade"

Tags: icons, actions

I'm trying to come up with an icon that would be understood to mean "upgrade" - the user should click on that icon if he wants to upgrade his application/subscription/whatever to a "premium" level.

I've searched the web but all I've found were either icons that included the text "upgrade" or icons that I, at least, would *not* understand to mean "upgrade".

So how can I convey the "upgrade" message with an icon?

**EDIT**

@closevoters See [this meta answer](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/a/725/77533) (highest voted there). I'm not asking for you to select between icons. I'm asking for the icon "idea" that conveys the message of upgrade.

Comment: Keep in mind that icons alone aren't enough. [Add a label.](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Level up icon]

Ok, on a more serious note:

I envision a badge or certificate-looking seal with an up arrow to indicate "Upgrade".

Something like this:

[image: Upgrade Badge/Icon]

Comment: The badge is a nice idea. It certainly conveys some sense of "premium". Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, it's almost always best not to use an icon without text if there isn't already a very, very commonly used icon for the desired action.

I was once running a comprehension test on potential users for the Waze gps app and almost no one could say what one of their icons was supposed to communicate because they had never seen it before.

Comment: Thanks. This is good advice. Unfortunately, I can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this icon helpful?

Description:

**Arrow:** Shows files needs to be downloaded.

**Plus:** Shows files are new.

**Horizontal Bar with three white circles:** Shows an electronic system where new files will be downloaded.

[image]

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Nice idea. Though about the little circles - I'm not sure they'll be clear when the icon is shrunk to size. But still a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: Its a good point but it helps sometimes. Also I wanted to know which file type are you planning to use. If you want I can send you a file for high resolution. I am not sure uploading here and downloading will decrease the quality of file.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use an icon that people already know.

The Apple Store uses this: [image: Apple Store Update]

The App Store uses this: [image: App Store Update]

Note that they both include a text label.